# How to remove div added dynamically from DOM, when mouse not hovering, using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that append a div element to the DOM when I hover an HTML element with a text that I look for:

```
document.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
const selectedText = e.target.innerText;

if (keywords[selectedText] !== undefined) {
    const existingPopup = document.querySelector(".popup");

  if (!existingPopup) {
    const popup = document.createElement("div");
    popup.className = "popup";
    popup.textContent = keywords[selectedText];

    popup.style.position = "absolute";
    popup.style.width = "300px";
    popup.style.height = "300px";
    popup.style.backgroundColor = "white";

    popup.style.top = `15px`;
    popup.style.right = `15px`;

    document.body.appendChild(popup);
  }
 }
});
```

The idea is display a div as a popup, and when the hover ends, remove the popup.

How could I remove that element that I added dynamically when the mouse leave it? I can't use jquery or modify the HTML adding static elements..

Comment: Use a `mouseout` listener to do something when you leave an element.